# Django template not found although it it exists in templates folder

Tags: django

> Django version 2.2.6

I have the following folder structure and was expecting Django to find index.html based as it is placed in the default location under templates.
Am I doing something wrong here? Did Django stop looking up the template paths by default?

```
-app
  |
  settings.py
  urls.py
  ...
  templates
   |
   base.html
   index.html
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Show your TEMPLATES setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path of your templates folder in settings.py.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Leave DIRS blank and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you are importing the home view page wrongly in the urls.py

Comment: Hi @Chelsea, please also provide the correct solution you think in your answer so that it will be much clear for the ones who asked the question.